# Excel powerquery with sharepoint workbook - We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, authentication, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a SharePoint 365 workbook as an Excel data source to another SharePoint 365 workbook.

I am signed in with the correct account according to Excel. When I try to add the data source, and authenticate as an "Organizational Account", it tells me I'm not signed in. I go through the sign in process and it clearly states "you are currently signed in". Then when I click "connect" it errors with: `We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again.`

I have confirmed I can access the file on SharePoint Online (and indeed, I created the file - I am the file owner).

I have cleared all global permissions from Excel. I also tried authenticating using `Basic` method, but get the same result.

I've tried both `Data > Get Data > From File > From Excel Workbook > Paste SharePoint URL` and `Data > From Web > Paste SharePoint URL`

**Excel shows I am signed in**

[image: Excel shows I am signed in]

**Get Data from Excel Workbook**

[image: Get Data from Excel Workbook]

**Paste SharePoint URL and click Open**

[image: Paste SharePoint URL]

**Dialog states I am not signed in, despite Excel showing I am signed in at top right corner**

[image: Dialog states I am not signed in]

**Click Sign In button and complete sign in process. Dialog now states I am signed in**

[image: Signed in]

**Click Connect - Authentication Error message displayed**

[image: Authentication error]

**Check `Data > Get Data > Data Source Settings > Global Permissions` as instructed on some online posts - global permissions are empty`

[image: Global permissions]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after doing all that OP did, I went into the Power Query editor and in Source, I pasted the path to the Sharepoint resource again (previously it had `%20` in place of spaces). After pasting a "normal" link with spaces, it works, despite the file name still having spaces represented by `%20`:

[image: Now it works]